# Improving groupby() performance

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

The original dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd
array = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
         'color': ['yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'white']}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df

id          color
1           yellow
1           red
1           yellow
1           red
2           yellow
3           white
```

I have transformed it to the following dataframe with get_dummies:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
df

   id  red  white  yellow
0   1    0      0       1
1   1    1      0       0
2   1    0      0       1
3   1    1      0       0
4   2    0      0       1
5   3    0      1       0
```

which I want to groupby() column 'id':

```
df.groupby(['id']).max()

    red  white  yellow
id                    
1     1      0       1
2     0      0       1
3     0      1       0
```

However, my original dataframe is 8,000 rows by 1,500,000 columns which makes this operation too slow.

Any ideas on how to make it quicker?

Comment: What is your data model that your dataframe is so exceptionally wide?

Comment: What do you mean by data model?

Comment: In this case, the schema of the dataframe (the types of the columns and what each row/column represents). In most situations, there are more rows than columns.

Comment: They are all integers (id and colors). The colors are 0 or 1.

Comment: How many groups do you have in 8000 rows?

Comment: @Corralien - about 800 groups

Comment: would be much appreciated if you provide the new data in a ready-to-use format. Just as you did with your first sample data

Comment: does this help: : ``df.groupby([*df]).size().clip(upper=1).unstack('color', fill_value=0)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Based on your original data frame, I would unique the data frame and pivot (or hot encode) it later. By this, you completely avoid any subsequent aggregation.

```
df_unique = df.drop_duplicates()
df_unique["val"] = 1
df_unique
    id  color   val
0   1   yellow  1
1   1   red     1
4   2   yellow  1
5   3   white   1

df_unique.set_index("id").pivot(columns="color").fillna(0)
    red     white   yellow
id          
1   1.0     0.0     1.0
2   0.0     0.0     1.0
3   0.0     1.0     0.0
```

#### Coding Alternatives

Please try reshaping your data (which is also time-consuming) but might be faster than your current wide format:

```
# first approach using melt.groupby.max 
pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'id').groupby(["id", "variable"]).max()

# second approach using melt.sort.groupby.first
pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'id').sort_values(by="variable", ascending=True).groupby(["id", "variable"]).first()
```

You can run this afterward to retain the desired shape again:

```
melted_and_aggregated_df.reset_index(level=["variable"]).pivot(columns=["variable"], values="value")
```

#### Data Size

Besides the pure coding efficiency, try to reduce your data.

- In case there are groups that only have a single row, you should use the max/first approach on the other groups only and combine the results afterward.
- Are there actually 1.5 million colors? Sounds enormous. Do you really need all of them or can it be reduced/aggregated priorly?

Comment: Thanks!!! Are you sure melting is quicker. Applying it to the short dataframe I have posted above it takes 3ms when the original groupby() takes 1ms

Comment: Colors are just an example. The realworld data is coded differently

Comment: No, I am not sure. It is just another way to address this problem. The main emphasis should be to reduce your data prior to aggregating. I doubt there is an option that would be very fast considering the large data size

Comment: no ... melting should not be quicker, you are extending the number of rows, which does not offer any efficiency. I'd suggest that a faster solution than groupby should be one that reduces the rows, and allows vectorised operations on the columns

Comment: @sammywemmy - thank you for your comment. The origin of this large dataframe is a get_dummies() command. Can a similar operation be performed without get_dummies()?

Comment: Can you share the original dataframe instead, share your final expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy - I have added the original data above. Thanks!

Comment: @mnist - works great! Thanks!